# error attributing items from scrapy into a database

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

am trying to insert items scraped through scrapy into a MySQL database (create a new database if none is present before), I followed an online tutorial since I have no idea how to do this but an error keeps happening.

am trying to store an item that contains 5 text fields into a database

here's my pipeline

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


import mysql.connector


class LinkPipeline(object):

    def _init_(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd = 'facebook123',
            database = 'link'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS link_tb""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table link_tb(
                        profile text,
                        post_url text,
                        action text,
                        url text,
                        date text
                        )""")

    def process_item(self,item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return(item)

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into link_tb values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item['profile'][0],
            item['post_url'][0],
            item['action'][0],
            item['url'][0],
            item['date'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

here's a part of my spider

```py
        if response.meta['flag'] == 'init':
            #parse root comment
            for root in response.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"root")]/div/div/div[count(@id)!=1 and contains("0123456789", substring(@id,1,1))]'): 
                new = ItemLoader(item=LinkItem(),selector=root)
                new.context['lang'] = self.lang
                new.add_xpath('profile', "substring-before(.//h3/a/@href, concat(substring('&', 1 div contains(.//h3/a/@href, 'profile.php')), substring('?', 1 div not(contains(.//h3/a/@href, 'profile.php')))))")
                new.add_xpath('action','.//div[1]//text()')
                new.add_xpath('date','.//abbr/text()')
                new.add_value('post_url',response.meta['link_url'])
                new.add_value('url',response.url)
                yield new.load_item()
```

I expect the item to be stored in my "link" database but I keep running into this error 
" self.cursor.execute("""insert into link_tb values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
AttributeError: 'LinkPipeline' object has no attribute 'cursor'"

Comment: python has problem with `self.cursor` but I don't see `self.cursor` in code. Maybe you have two files - one with `self.cursor` which is used by scraper and second with `self.curr` which you show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the constructor as `_init_` instead of `__init__`

Comment: thanks ! I never worked with this before so i sometimes forget stuff like this, much appreciated !